# Is there any event/intent to let me know when system crash or reboot?

Tags: android, database, crash, reboot

I have implement a feature that will update the database when needed.

(ex. change one of the column value of the database to B)

If system crash or reboot or something that is out of order,

is there any thing I can know then I can handle to recover the database back?

(ex. recover one of the column value of the database back to A)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED” />
```

Define `BroadcastReceiver` which does the actions you want.

You will need in your `manifest` sth like:

```
<receiver android:name=”.MyReceiver”>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=”android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED” />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hi, Sherif:
Thanks for your reply.
I think BOOT_COMPLETED should be sent after boot.
But I want to know when reboot(such as command : adb reboot) or crash happen so that I can handle to recover my database back.
(The timing should be: crash/reboot -> recover database -> power off )
Then next time when the system restart, the database should already be recovered.

Comment: It is impossible to catch a crash. Even if you caught it, you wont be able to execute code

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When device completes, it Broadcasts a intent and by registering to this broadcast u can get the call:

```
         public class YourReceiverName extends BroadcastReceiver{
            @Override
            public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

                if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
                //Do your task here....
                        }
                }
         }
```

add permission to manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

and register this receiver in manifest file:

```
    <receiver android:name="Your receiver name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and for Database, it is upto you how you handle it and what your app demands.

Answer (score 0):

A crash, by definition, can't be caught.

That's what makes a crash a crash.